# How to add facebook like/share button to every new text I post?

Tags: nodes, social-network

I would like to add facebook like/share button to every new post on news site without doing it manually every single time I post new text. Similar question has already been answered, but I wonder if there is solution that doesn't include much code intervention, for example, is it possible to do it just with Facebook Like Button Module or something alike. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you,
You can achieve this with two module [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [facebook](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_social)
after enabling both module go to the structure tab of drupal,click on this[image]

put Fcaebook application Id here:

[image]

You can create application id from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
on reference to ur facebook account.
Than inside Facebook social go to "**Presets**" 
click on add 
fill up this form
[image]

for like button put only the name and select radio button of "facebook like button plugin" and select your content type,
save the form,
Go to view to create a new view,

Select respective field of your node and below that select the "Node:Facebook Social plugin", on settings of this field put your preset name as below

[image]

Finally you will get the face book like button on every row of your view.

Comment: thanks. I will try, if I'll have no luck with fb like button module.

Answer (score 1):

It sound as if like you're looking for the [Facebook Like Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/fblikebutton) module.

From the project page:

> Rather than having to manually copy/paste the Like this on Facebook code for each piece of content you (or your users) create, this module will automatically add that code to the end of each chosen node type. You are able to add a Like button which likes a given URL (static, e.g. your homepage) or/and put a dynamic Like button on your page to like the page you are actually visiting.

(Btw: It looks like you're mentioning this module in your question. If you have a *problem* with using this module, you need to spell out what the problem is.)

Comment: Like buttons doesn't appear in full node view, only in teasers, although both options are chosen in module configuration.

Comment: @natttan, all I can say is that is works as expected on my site (both for teasers and full node view). You need to configure permissions for non-admin to see the button (People/Permissions - Access FB Like button), but that works equal for both teasers and full view. I put the button in the "Content area" for both. Rest of settings are the default. Tested with Firefox, Chrome and MSIE. Tested on a clean install of Drupal 7.28.